# Installing CUDA on my Ubuntu 18.04 system

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, opencv, cuda

I want to install CUDA on my system to run OpenCV. 
I have the NVIDIA 1050 Ti Mobile which supports the driver 390.116. I tried to install CUDA 10 and failed, I think because of the driver incompatibility. 
According to the wiki https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/CUDA, it seems that I can only CUDA 9.1, which isn't supported in Ubuntu 18.04.

How can I have CUDA on 18.04? Will I need a different GPU? Will I need to downgrade my OS to run CUDA?

Comment: How did you try to install CUDA 10? Why can't you try to install CUDA 9.1 in same way?

Comment: Actually updating the driver helped fixed the CUDA installation issue! The 1050 Ti supports the 418 driver as well, so when I updated that I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a version of CUDA which is compatible with your drivers. You can check the compatibility from [CUDA release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html), for driver version 390.116 the highest supported version of CUDA is 9.1.

You can download different versions from [CUDA download page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). You could download the runfile and install the required components in `/usr/local`. You should **not** install the driver which the installer suggests, as it would replace your distribution packaged driver (and possibly cause issues with package management/kernel updates later on).

Comment: CUDA 9.1 isn't supported on Ubuntu 18.04, it would have needed to downgrade to 16.04 to run it. I decided to update the Nividia driver, however. I'm running the 418 after which the CUDA 10 installation worked fine.

Comment: "You should not install the driver which the installer suggests, as it would replace your distribution packaged driver (and possibly cause issues with package management/kernel updates later on)."

I haven't had any issues yet, and hopefully (fingers crossed) I won;t have problems later. 418 was the recommended installation when I ran $ ubuntu-drivers devices.

Comment: Even that 9.1 is not officially *supported* on 18.04, the older 16.04 likely works just fine (I am using CUDA 9.1 on Debian sid without issues)